# Derivative of absolute value of a vector with reference to certain components?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I'm a bit confused by this notation.. 
$$
\frac{d^\mathbf{n}}{d(-\mathbf{r})^\mathbf{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\lvert r\rvert}\right)
$$

where r is a vector and 
$$
\mathbf{r}^\mathbf{n} = (x^{n_x},y^{n_y},z^{n_z})
$$ 
and $n$ = some components, say $(0,0,1)$ or $(2,0,0)$

How do i differentiate this? Sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm confused.. For example if, $n=(0,0,0)$ then does the differentiation become $d/d(1)=0$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The notation is unknown to me. Let us start with $r^n$ what is $x^{n_x}$ supposed to mean?

Comment: It reminds me remotely of $\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}\partial/\partial \mathbf{r} = \grad_r$. It would also make sense to apply a gradient or maybe negative gradient to a scalar field.

Comment: Ok, so i think i figured some things out, assuming some things. If deriving zeroeth order means not deriving at all, that would mean that for every component in n that is 0, you do not derive that component in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ so, if $n=(0,0,0)$ then 
$$
\frac{d^\mathbf{n}}{d(-\mathbf{r})^\mathbf{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\lvert r\rvert}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{\lvert r\rvert}\right)
$$

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle \frac{d^{n}}{d\mathbf{r^n}}=\frac{\partial^{n_x+n_y+n_z}}{\partial x^{n_x}\partial y^{n_y}\partial z^{n_z}}$?

Comment: That's what i assumed in the end, but the notation above is what I'm given..